# Python proxy opening program

Tags: python, python-requests, python-3.5

This is my first post on stack exchange for python.  I currently have code to get proxies.  However, for python 3.5.4, I can not get a program that can use the proxies and open them in chorme/firefox.  I am trying to get the porgram to open mutiple tabs, each through a different porxy, through python.

Here is what i tried:

```
import requests
ttp_proxy  = "http://10.10.1.10:3128"
https_proxy = "https://10.10.1.11:1080"
ftp_proxy   = "ftp://10.10.1.10:3128"

proxyDict = { 
              "http"  : ttp_proxy, 
              "https" : https_proxy, 
              "ftp"   : ftp_proxy
            }

url = 'http://google.com'
r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxyDict)





while True:
    r = r.get(url)
    print(r.text)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: what is the issue with the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). It's great that you've shown what you've tried, but it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. To launch a page in Chrome/Firefox, check the [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/webbrowser.html) module.If you want to configure the browser to use the new proxy, [there are command line arguments](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches) - not compatible with `webbrowser`, perhaps use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: @PYA issue is that there is always errors when i run and that it does not open the tab.

Comment: @itisyeetimetoday so `print()` doesnt return anything?

Comment: @PYA, yes, the print does not return anything